# Vaadin: Bind Enum values to ComboBox (ConversionException)

Tags: java, data-binding, combobox, enums, vaadin

I want to bind enum values from my Model to a ComboBox. What I tried:

Model:

```
public class Model{
public enum Status {
        Neu, Analyse, Pruefung, Freigabe, OnTheRoad, EOL, CANCELLED;
        public String getCaption() {
            return name();
        }

        public int getId() {
            return ordinal();
        }
    }

    private Status status;
}
```

Form:

```
public class MyForm extends CustomComponent{

private final BeanFieldGroup<Model> binder;

@PropertyId("status")
 private final ComboBox cStatus = new ComboBox("Status");

public MyForm (Model model) {
        final HorizontalLayout content = new HorizontalLayout();
        content.addComponent(buildContent());

        // Now use a binder to bind the members
        binder = new BeanFieldGroup<>(Model.class);

        // We need an item data source before we create the fields to be able to
        // find the properties, otherwise we have to specify them by hand
        final BeanItem bean = new BeanItem<>(model);
        binder.setItemDataSource(bean);
        binder.buildAndBindMemberFields(this);

        setCompositionRoot(content);
}

private buildContent(){
        final FormLayout basicContent = new FormLayout();

        final BeanContainer<Integer, Status> container = new BeanContainer<>(Status.class);
        container.setBeanIdProperty("id");
        container.addAll(EnumSet.allOf(Status.class));
        cStatus.setContainerDataSource(container);
        cStatus.setItemCaptionPropertyId("caption");
        basicContent.addComponent(cStatus);

        return basicContent;
}

public void commit() throws CommitException {
        binder.commit(); // This is what causes the error
}
}
```

When i call commit() I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter$ConversionException: Unable to convert value of type java.lang.Integer to model type class com.xx.test.entities.def.Model$Status. No converter is set and the types are not compatible.
    at com.vaadin.data.util.converter.ConverterUtil.convertToModel(ConverterUtil.java:181) ~[vaadin-server-7.5.6.jar:7.5.6]
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.convertToModel(AbstractField.java:751) ~[vaadin-server-7.5.6.jar:7.5.6]
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.convertToModel(AbstractField.java:731) ~[vaadin-server-7.5.6.jar:7.5.6]
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.getConvertedValue(AbstractField.java:817) ~[vaadin-server-7.5.6.jar:7.5.6]
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.commit(AbstractField.java:253) ~[vaadin-server-7.5.6.jar:7.5.6]
    at com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup.commitFields(FieldGroup.java:509) ~[vaadin-server-7.5.6.jar:7.5.6]
    at com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup.commit(FieldGroup.java:481) ~[vaadin-server-7.5.6.jar:7.5.6]
    ... 49 more
```

Is there any way to bind the Enum of my Model to the ComboBox ?

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE (André Schild answer):

I want to display the String representation of the Enum values, so I think I need to Use String instead of Integer? I figured out that there actually is a build in "StringToEnumConverter". However, I tried it with the StringToEnumConverter and my own "StringToStatusConverter":

```
cStatus.setConverter((Converter) new StringToEnumConverter());
cStatus.addItems(EnumSet.allOf(Status.class));`
// cStatus.addItem(Status.CANCELLED); // Did not work
// cStatus.setConvertedValue(Status.EOL); // Did not work
```

Now I'm getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: xx.xxx.xxx.entities.modeldefdef.Model$Status cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.vaadin.data.util.converter.StringToEnumConverter.convertToModel(StringToEnumConverter.java:32) ~[vaadin-server-7.5.6.jar:7.5.6]
```

... for both Converters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your buildContent() method write:

```
// ...
final BeanItemContainer<Status> container = new BeanItemContainer<>(Status.class);
container.addAll(EnumSet.allOf(Status.class));
cStatus.setContainerDataSource(container);
cStatus.setItemCaptionPropertyId("caption");
basicContent.addComponent(cStatus);
// ...
```

Why? Your ComboBox is bound to a Property of type Status by your FieldGroup. But your current Container BeanContainer has the type Integer, that is the type of the container's IDs. To fix that the container's ID types have to match the property's type. This is done by using the BeanItemContainer, which uses the Bean type as object ID. [Here](http://blog.oio.de/2014/04/25/select-nested-javabeans-vaadin-fieldgroup/) the problem is explained in more detail.

Comment: After adding `container.setBeanIdProperty("id");` the enum can be applied to the ComboBox. The only thing what causes still problems is calling `binder.commit();` before I persist the Object. This is the error message: `Caused by: com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter$ConversionException: Unable to convert value of type java.lang.Integer to model type class xx.xxx.xx.entities.xxxxxdef.Model$Status. No converter is set and the types are not compatible.
 at com.vaadin.data.util.converter.ConverterUtil.convertToModel(ConverterUtil.java:181) ~[vaadin-server-7.5.6.jar:7.5.6]`

Comment: You need to implement a converter that implements Converter<Object, Model.Status>! It's because the Container's presentation type is Object. In that container you convert Status objects to integers and vice versa. Still, to use the BeanItemContainer here is the much simpler solution than to use the BeanContainer with integers as IDs.

Comment: Take a look at the converter on the mentioned page (http://blog.oio.de/2014/04/25/select-nested-javabeans-vaadin-fieldgroup/). The important section is "Bringing together item ID type and property type".

Comment: Sorry my bad. I used `BeanContainer` instead of `BeanItemContainer`. Now it works like it's supposed to be, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin has the concept of `Converter` which transform from a internal representation to a external representation.

You will need to implement the Converter interface, and then specify to use it.

```
public class IntegerToModelStatusConverter implements Converter<Integer, Model$Status>
```

and

```
final ComboBox statusField = new ComboBox("Status");
statusField .setConverter(new IntegerToModelStatusConverter());
```

The integer is the int value of the corresponding enum element.

There is a [wiki](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/) entry describing this in more details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779247/vaadin-why-i-cant-set-a-converter-to-a-combobox explains why setting this converter doesn't work.