# Vaadin: Use custom Converter for ListSelect

Tags: java, type-conversion, converters, vaadin

Is it possible to use a custom Converter for the ListSelect Component?
This is what I tried:

```
ListSelect ls = new ListSelect();
ls.setConverter((Converter) new MyCustomConverter());

ObjectToDisplay ots = new ObjectToDisplay();

// ls.setConvertedValue(ots ); // Converter is called but ListSelect stays empty 
lsConstruction.addItem(ots ); // Did not work
```

However, the ListSelect stays empty after adding a value.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you really need a converter, that is conversion in two directions, or do you just want to configure how the object is displayed? If the latter is the case, you don't need a converter. You set the item caption with `setItemCaption()` or you use one of the item caption modes.

Comment: @A.Meier My use case is to insert objects and display some values of the object in a specific format. Later I want to collect all of the inserted Objects . Could i achieve that with  `setItemCaption()` ?

Comment: Yes. You would insert objects of type ObjectToDisplay into your ListSelect or better underlying Container and set the caption for each item with `setItemCaption()` in your desired format.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, please check it off then.

Comment: @A.Meier Yes it worked, thanks! Now I got another question: Would it be possible to bind an ArrayList<ObjectToDisplay> to the ListSelect with automatically using the desired caption? This is what I mean: `binder = new BeanFieldGroup<>(ClassWithObjectToDisplayArray.class); final BeanItem bean = new BeanItem<>(classWithObjectToDisplayArray);
  binder.setItemDataSource(bean);
  binder.buildAndBindMemberFields(this);` and for the ListSelect `@PropertyId("objectToDisplay") private final ListSelect ls = new ListSelect();`

Comment: Your can select properties as captions by using `setItemCaptionPropertyId("the caption property")`. But please put that into a new Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setItemCaption()`:

```
final ListSelect ls = new ListSelect ();
final BeanItemContainer<ObjectToDisplay> container = new BeanItemContainer<>(ObjectToDisplay.class, objectList);
ls.setContainerDataSource(container);
for (final ObjectToDisplay o : objectList){
    ls.setItemCaption(o, yourDesiredFormatFunction(o));
}
```

Adding object programmatically would be done with `container.addItem(object)`.

Regarding the use of Converters: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779247/vaadin-why-i-cant-set-a-converter-to-a-combobox) elaborates on Converters used with AbstractSelect implementations such as ListSelect and ComboBoxes.